# SSL Certificate for multiple servers

Tags: networking, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I want to use same SSL certificate in multiple servers, which type of SSL certificate should I use? Unified SSL certificate? or Wildcard SSL certificate?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Any certificate can be installed on multiple servers but your question requires more information on how you want to be advised. 
A wildcard SSL certificate will secure any subdomain that the Wildcard character is on. So if you have a certificate for *.domain.com then you can secure

- secure.domain.com
- bob.domain.com
- charlie.domain.com

and the list can go on, however it won't work for sub.secure.domain.com as the wildcard only does the single level.

A unified certificate, depending on the provider would only give you 3 subdomains. 
mail, owa and autodiscover.domain.com

Also a standard certificate you can generally add SAN's too which will allow you to add subdomains under extra costs, but if you are only looking to secure 2 subdomains then a certificate with 1 SAN would be cheaper in most cases than a wildcard.

Give us an example of what you are trying to do and people can probably advise you better.

Comment: Is wildcard SSL certificate needed for unique domain with different TLD? (example.com, example.net, etc...)

Comment: @Dez I've certificate for *.abc.com and Can i use this certificate for dev.abc.com:9003 ?

Answer (score 6):

Securing Multiple Servers With One SSL Certificate

To move your certificate between servers you will need to install the certificate on the same web server that you generated the CSR from. You can then export the SSL certificate and its private key to a PKCS#12 file, or if it is an non-Windows based server you will be able to copy the key and certificate files.

Click [HERE](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1216451-securing-multiple-servers---ssl-certificates) for more details:

Comment: It doesn't matter what type of SSL certificate that you have.

Comment: I've certificate for *.abc.com and Can i use this certificate for dev.abc.com:9003 ?

Comment: @rgx yes you can. Nothing related to ssl though, your web server would have to be configured as a proxy to a different url, say `dev.abc.com/9003`, for any requests to `dev.abc.com:9003`.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard SSL Certificates allow you to secure multiple sub domains on the same domain name, thereby saving you time and money, and of course you do not need to manage multiple SSL Certificates on the same server.